# PostgreSQL SELECT in LHS of WHERE Clause

Tags: postgresql

I might be asking for the wrong solution but this is the only way I know how to express my issue.

I am trying to create a view that includes rows for the last day of each month. The way the table is constructed is that a status value is set with a start date and an end date. On any given day, objects in the table will have a status that may have been static for months or may have been changed the day before. New rows are only created when the status changes.

So, for example, if I want a snapshot of the status of all objects on 2016-01-31 I would use this query:

```
select * from table
where '2016-01-31' between dtstart and dtend
```

I want my view to include the last day of each month in a range from some past date through the present. I can create that range like this:

```
select (d.d + '1 mon'::interval - '1 day'::interval)::date AS monthend
from generate_series('2016-01-01'::date::timestamp with time zone, now(), '1 mon'::interval) d(d)
```

The only way that I can think of to accomplish this is to pass the list of dates to the LHS of the WHERE clause but that doesn't seem to be possible. I'm sure that I could create a table with some loops in psql but I'm not very familiar with that language.

Any suggestions?

Table

```
unit |   dtstart  |    dtend   | status
---------------------------------------
01   | 2016-01-01 | 2016-05-30 | rented
02   | 2016-01-01 | 2016-03-14 | vacant
01   | 2016-06-01 | 2016-07-15 | vacant
01   | 2016-07-16 | 2016-07-31 | rented
02   | 2016-03-15 | 2016-04-15 | rented
02   | 2016-04-16 | 2016-12-31 | vacant
```

Desired Output for Jan - Jun

```
   date    | unit | status
--------------------------
2016-01-31 |  01  | rented
2016-02-29 |  01  | rented
2016-03-31 |  01  | rented
2016-04-30 |  01  | rented
2016-05-31 |  01  | rented
2016-06-30 |  01  | vacant
2016-07-31 |  01  | rented
2016-01-31 |  02  | vacant
2016-02-29 |  02  | vacant
2016-03-31 |  02  | rented
2016-04-30 |  02  | vacant
2016-05-31 |  02  | vacant
2016-06-30 |  02  | vacant
```

SOLUTION:

```
select 
ends.monthend,
us.*
from y_unit_status us
join (
     select (d.d + '1 mon'::interval - '1 day'::interval)::date AS monthend
     from generate_series('2016-01-01'::date::timestamp with time zone, now(), '1 mon'::interval) d(d)) ends
on ends.monthend between dtstart and dtend
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the two queries:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   mytable t
JOIN   (SELECT (d.d + '1 MON'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)::DATE AS monthend
        FROM   GENERATE_SERIES('2016-01-01'::DATE::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, 
                               NOW(),
                               '1 MON'::INTERVAL) d(d)) ends 
ON     ends.monthend BETWEEN dtstart AND dtend
```